# UnsupportedOperationException - the removeAll method is not supported by this collection (Java Collections)

Tags: java, collections

```
Set<Badge> availableBadges = myService.getAvailableBadges();
List<Badge> allBadges = Arrays.asList(Badge.values());
allBadges.removeAll(availableBadges);
/* Badge is an enumn */
```

what collections do support remove all ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` returns a partially unmodifiable implementation (in part of `remove*` methods - thanks to @LouisWasserman for the remark) of the `List` interface.

**EDIT 1:** Use an `ArrayList` wrapper on it: `new ArrayList<Badge>(allBadges);`

Comment: `Arrays.asList` isn't quite unmodifiable; it supports `set`, but not `remove` or `add`.

Answer (score 4):

Your collection might be unmodifiable.

You need to create new List

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(unmodifiableList);
```

Now your list is modifiable and you can perform remove and `removeAll` operations.